# Electric potential energy and signs

Tags: electrostatics, potential-energy, conventions

I know that electric potential is negative near a negative charge and positive near a positive charge. But does this mean a small positive 'test' charge has a negative electric potential energy near a negative charge and a small negative charge would have a positive?

Answer (score 1):

You can't state what the potential energy of a system is in absolute terms, you can only talk about the difference in potential energy between two states. In your example, you are quite free to define the potential energy of two nearby particles having the same charge as anything you like, positive, negative or zero.

For example, what is the potential energy of somebody standing at sea level? We usually define this as zero, but that's just for computational simplicity. If a giant trap door opened and you fell a further 10m below sea level, you would become painfully and perhaps fatally aware that your potential energy at sea level wasn't zero. In fact its undefined. What is defined is the difference between your potential energy at sea level and your potential energy 10m below sea level.

Answer (score 0):

Start with the physical meaning of the potential energy.

The potential energy (of a particle for instance) is the work that a particle or you and me have to provide AGAINST all the forces in the universe to exist at a given point in space, starting from an initial position. In principle, as we consider that all forces vanish at infinity, the initial point is taken there, but one might as well consider an equilibrium position where no force applies.

So to answer your specific question, whether positive or negative charge q you have, the only way this charge q can exist at point $\vec{r}$ is because it has provided energy to work against the forces that apply onto it. Here if we consider only the electric force,

$$Ep(\vec{r}_f) = - \int_{\infty}^{\vec{r}_f} \vec{F}(\vec{r})\cdot d\vec{r}$$ with $$ \vec{F} = q \vec{E}(\vec{r})$$

I neglected time variation for clarity. The minus sign is extremely important as it gives the physical meaning of the potential energy (it translates the above "AGAINST"). If Ep is positive, then it means that the particle has to provide energy (taken from its kinetic energy) because the external forces oppose to the motion of the particle.